# Passing a CSRF token

Tags: ajax, csrf-protection

I'm trying to pass a CSRF token in a form that is submitted via a javascript (not jquery) AJAX function. The accepted wisdom appears to be to include the token as a hidden input in the actual form. As I see it the problem with this is that the contents of a hidden input can easily be seen using a browsers inspect facility. So is there a more secure way to pass the token?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue that the CSRF token is accessible in the source code because it's not meant to be hidden to the client browser. And when I say "hidden" here I am not talking about the HTML property "hidden" of a form, but the  disclosure of the token, should it be by analyzing page source, script execution or network traffic (really hidden).

You must understand why CSRF tokens are useful. If an attacker creates a malicious webpage, hosted under an external domain, which POST or GET to your website, then he can expect an authenticated user (a victim - with an open session and sesion ID in cookie) to perform the POST/GET: the victim's browser will detect the target URL, add the cookies/session ID to the GET/POST headers, and perform the action on behalf of the authenticated user (eg: "destroy my account").

If you create a random CSRF token in the source, the attacker cannot read it (because he cannot load the page on behalf of the victim's browser and read its content, thanks to Cross-Domain content segregation) and hence cannot build a malicious page which will perform a GET or POST.

As for other methods, other websites use a unique static CSRF token (generated per user on session init), which is saved in cookies and included in the forms of the sites through JS. The result is the same, the token will be part of the form submit (and so accessible to the client's browser). You just avoid producing CSRF tokens for each form and the server can easily compare the token with the client's session data rather than performing side-channel token management.

Comment: The app I'm building actually has several forms each on its own page. I was envisaging generating a new CSRF token each time one of the forms is loaded rather than having a static token.

Comment: I would go the other way for the sake of simplicity and maintainability. I know banking-level platforms storing the CSRF token inside cookie and reusing the same on all forms. There is no real added value on security side if the CSRF is changed every time, because if it is leaked just once it means the entire user session is leaked, making CSRF the least of the problematic issue. But in the end, if automated enough, both are viable solutions.